# I don't quite understand the callback function with a parameter of err or error

Tags: javascript, callback

I have trouble understanding the callback function with an parameter of err(error) I complete understand the callback function but find this specific topic a bit hard to understand because I don't know why and how a value or something is passed into the function without me calling the function and sending anything as parameters.so this is my first question.

My second question is :

I've been trying to use

```
object.insertMany([object1,object2],function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
```

So I noticed something about these kind of callback function such as

```
document.querySelector("#class").keypress(function(evt){
})
```

where I only use them when something triggers them, so is it true that I can only use those kind of functions such as function(err) or function(evt) in specific cases like those and I can not make a function with the err parameter such as this

```
function addition(x,y){
  var result =x+y;
  return result;
}

addition(1,2):
```

Comment: `keypress` and `insertMany` work in a predefined way, they take a function as an argument, & then call it, providing it with specific arguments. In the case of `keypress` the argument it supplies the function is the `evt` argument. For `insertMany` the argument it supplies to your callback function is `err`. So the arguments you receive in the function you supply is controlled by the method that you pass your function into. I'm not too what you're asking in regards to the `addition` function though... this is a normal function, and not a callback, so it doesn't receive `err` or `evt`.

Comment: I was trying to ask that if some functions aren't predefined as keypress or insertMany, would it work if I pass err, or evt into the function.Because since in the two predefined methods, I can name the err anything I want, so I was wondering if the parameter in normal function would inherit that property as well. I am still  relatively new to programming and I only got around 2 years of experience. So I am sorry that if some parts of my question confused you. Anyways, thank you for the help. I really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first couple of examples the `insertMany` and `keypress` functions are responsible for supplying the callback function with a parameter. (there isn't anything special about `err` or errors, the functions would pass the error like you would any other parameter)

If want to write a function that supplies a parameter to a callback you definitely can!

```js
function addition(x,y, callback){
  var result =x+y;
  var error = isNaN(result) ? 'Bad input!' : undefined;
  callback(result, error);
}

addition(1, 2, function(res, err) {
  console.log(res);
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

addition('apple', 2, function(res, err) {
  console.log(res);
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```